# Similar \hourglass and \lozengeminus symbols

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to get similar `\hourglass` (⧖) and `\lozengeminus` (⟠) symbols, i.e. with identical triangles?

With both `fdsymbol` and `stix` packages, `\lozengeminus` is much larger than `\hourglass`.

The goal is to have two "opposite" operators with down-up triangles and up-down triangles, i.e. the second one being obtained by exchanging the triangles.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could define a `tikzpicture` as a command. Then you could control the size of the two symbols that you want to create.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\hour}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (6pt,0) -- (0,12pt) -- (6pt,12pt) -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\loz}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw (0,6pt) -- (3pt,12pt) -- (6pt,6pt);
    \draw (0,6pt) -- (6pt,6pt);
    \draw (0,6pt) -- (3pt,0) -- (6pt,6pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

This is an example of \hour. 

This is an example of \loz.

\end{document}
```

These specific definitions would look like this:

[image: Definitions of tikz commands output]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option is to build it out of two copies of `\triangle` with `stackengine`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}


$
\stackanchor[-4.1pt]{$\triangle$}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\triangle$}} 
\stackanchor[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\triangle$}}{$\triangle$}
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another version with `picture` mode that scales with the math styles. Modify the width/height according to your taste (shown with the width set to 0.33333em).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lozengeminus}{%
  \mathbin{% a binary operation symbol
  \mspace{1mu}% some sidebearing
  \mathpalette\vinc@lozengeminus\relax}% the symbol
  \mspace{1mu}% some sidebearing
}
\newcommand{\vinc@lozengeminus}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\unitlength}{$\m@th#1\mspace{6mu}$}% 1/3 of an em
  \begin{picture}(1,1.732)
  \vinc@linethickness{#1}
  \roundcap\roundjoin
  \Line(0.5,0)(1,0.866)(0.5,1.732)(0,0.866)(0.5,0)
  \Line(0,0.866)(1,0.866)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\hourglass}{%
  \mathbin{% a binary operation symbol
  \mspace{1mu}% some sidebearing
  \mathpalette\vinc@hourglass\relax}% the symbol
  \mspace{1mu}% some sidebearing
}
\newcommand{\vinc@hourglass}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\unitlength}{$\m@th#1\mspace{6mu}$}% 1/3 of an em
  \begin{picture}(1,1.732)
  \vinc@linethickness{#1}
  \roundcap\roundjoin
  \Line(0,0)(1,1.732)(0,1.732)(1,0)(0,0)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\vinc@linethickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.8\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 0.8\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle0.8\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x+a\lozengeminus b$
$\scriptstyle x+a\lozengeminus b$
$\scriptscriptstyle x+a\lozengeminus b$

$x+a\hourglass b$
$\scriptstyle x+a\hourglass b$
$\scriptscriptstyle x+a\hourglass b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could build both symbols to suit your needs. Here's a solution with the `picture` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setunitlength}{\setlength{\unitlength}{\f@size pt}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\hourglass}{%
    \setunitlength%
    \begin{picture}(.3,.6)
        \roundcap
        \put( 0, 0){\line( 1,2){.3}}
        \put(.3, 0){\line(-1,2){.3}}
        \put( 0, 0){\line( 1,0){.3}}
        \put( 0,.6){\line( 1,0){.3}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\newcommand*{\lozengeminus}{%
    \begin{picture}(.3,.6)
        \roundcap
        \put(  0,.3){\line(1, 0){.3}}
        \put(  0,.3){\line(1, 2){.15}}
        \put(  0,.3){\line(1,-2){.15}}
        \put(.15, 0){\line(1, 2){.15}}
        \put(.15,.6){\line(1,-2){.15}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\begin{document}
{\small \hourglass \lozengeminus} 
{\hourglass \lozengeminus} 
{\large \hourglass \lozengeminus}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The packagee `oplotsymbl` provides `\rhombuslineh` which might be close to what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{oplotsymbl}

\begin{document}

$\hourglass \rhombuslineh$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a bit better, but they are still very different.